# jQuery: How to undelegate a broad delegate on one table column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's the scenario:

I am creating a dblclick delegate on a bunch of table cells that contain a class called 'canEdit'. In a specific instance, I want to remove this delegate, and add a column-based delegate that overwrites the existing one.

Here's what I have:

```
$('#' + tableID).delegate('tbody tr td.canEdit', 'dblclick', function () {
// Code Here
});
```

When a specific property is set, this is what is run:

```
$('#' + tableID).undelegate('tbody tr td.canEdit', 'dblclick');
$('#' + tableID).delegate('tbody tr td:nth-child(' + index + ').canEdit.select', 'dblclick', function () {
// Code Here 
});
```

I am assuming one of the issues is that I'm removing the delegate on everything. Is there a way I can just overwrite and/or remove the first delegate only on the column? Any ideas of a workaround without having to create an entirely new class?

Comment: From jQuery 1.7, `delegate()` and `undelegate()` are deprecated in favour of `on()` and `off()`. Events can be [namespaced](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) to make them removable individually or in groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a conditional to run different code within the handler

```
$('#' + tableID).delegate('tbody tr td.canEdit', 'dblclick', function () {
   if( $(this).index()==7) ){
      /* code for 8th column*/
    }else{
      /*  code for other columns*/
    }
});
```